# Parallelizing code sse intrinsics functions c with openmp

Tags: openmp, sse2

I have a c code with intrinsics functions `sse2`. I am trying to parallelize this code. 
This code has recursive type sentences:

```
 *dex = _mm_add_pd(*dex,temp2);
```

I can not use the clause reduction, because I think that can only be used with type operators +, -, * ... and no pointers.

What should I do?

Thank you very much and greetings to all.

Comment: Just wondering, does the reduction clause work on overloaded C++ operators?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you encounter recursive stuff in openmp only parallel sections and tasks can help you.